# Thread.sleep() effect on MBeans in JVM

Tags: java

Is there any effect that Thread.sleep() has on the process running on the JVM? Does the process still exist on the JVM? Does it still expose MBeans that can be seen on JConsole? Or do the process metrics disappear and reload when the process thread is woken up?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` does not do anything with MBeans or the process running the JVM and it does not temporarily make MBeans disappear. If you see something that looks like this happening in your application, then the cause is something else.

Comment: Hi @Jesper , is there anything with `Thread.sleep()` that would force a context switch (to show up) in the JVM?

Comment: What do you mean with "force a context switch to show up in the JVM"?

Comment: Let me clarify. I have two types of applications running on the JVM. Both of them are similar in the way that they work. One outputs data to network; the other receives this data. But when I connect to JConsole, for the one that receives data, the MBeans come up consistently. Whereas for the one that sends data, the MBeans come up, then vanish and come back up after some time. This happens continuously. It looks like it is constantly refreshing the MBeans. I just had a thought that maybe the process is going to sleep and switching out of the JVM.

Comment: No, that is not how processes work. A process runs one program. A process cannot be running the JVM and then "switch out of the JVM" and start doing something completely different.